# Why environmental variable returns none in Linux?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, vim, linux-headers

In windows to set a new variable = value we can simply add it to the environmental variable. However, in linux, looks a bit tough. this is the procedure which I followed:

Open Terminal and write:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

then press the keyboard "i" and then define the variable as follow:

```
Test_MyVariable='Tessst'
export Test_MyVariable
PATH=$PATH:Test_MyVariable/bin
```

then `:wq`

after $echo I see the variable:

```
echo $Test_MyVariable
```

and it returns:

> Tessst

but in my sublime Text it returns None.

```
import os
new_v= os.environ.get('Test_MyVariable')
print(new_v)
```

> None

I even checked all available os.environ but I can't find my `Test_MyVariable`.
Furthermore, I also tried with `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` and added variable to them, but the same result. Could please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `Test_MyVariable='Tessst'` without the white-spaces

Comment: first of all don't use `vim` use `nano` this isn't the 70's . Second, for what you're doing I would recomend you edit `/etc/environment` instead. you'll find the format is quite resemblant. you'll have to `source /etc/environment` and reboot for the changes to apply though. you can do this in .bashrc as well and then the command to apply it is `source .bashrc` and the effect is immediate but only for your user. lastly don't add spaces, those will be interpreted as "next argument"

Comment: @SimonSudler tnx, yes I am aware of that. Here just was a typo

Comment: @tatsu tnx, I will try this one and let you know a bit later

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Do you call your Python script from the shell where you set the environment variable? `export` only influences the current shell (and its children). Also are you calling `get('Test_MyVariable ')` literally (with the space)? @tatsu [`vim`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) is much more powerful than `nano`. You might not like it but please don’t discourage people from using it.

Comment: @tatsu If the user _can_ use `vim`, then it isn’t necessary to point them to a simpler editor, moreover using an opinion-based argument. For example, `vim` provides syntax highlighting for `.bashrc` by default while `nano` doesn’t.

Comment: @tatsu tnx again, howere I don't think if using vim or nano makes any difference since I need a limited feature which both will support.

Comment: @Melebius, tnx, I am launching the python script which is located on my desktop, but have no idea where is the location of environmental variables. I will check

Comment: @tatsu please keep opinions out of the comments. And do not suggest editing system-wide files to make a change for a single user!

Comment: in a terminal do ... source ~/.bashrc ... then in same terminal execute your source code

Comment: @ElisaFo please [edit] your question and explain exactly how you are launching the python script. You say "*but in my sublime Text it returns None*". Does that mean you are running the python from within sublime? You also said "*I am launching the python script which is located on my desktop*". Does that mean you are double clicking the script? Or running it in a terminal with `python ~/Desktop/foo.py`? Something else? The environment the script runs in will depend completely on how you are launching it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define a variable in `~/.bashrc`, that variable will be present as soon as `~/.bashrc` is "sourced" (read). This only happens when you start a new shell (e.g. when you open a new terminal).

So, if you add the new line to your `.bashrc` file, you will then need to open a new terminal and run your python script there. Alternatively, you can run `source ~/.bashrc` to source it into the current shell.

Now, you mention sublime but don't really explain why that's relevant, so I will assume you are running your python script inside the sublime editor somehow. Presumably, it has some sort of shell emulator. If that is the case, then the details of how and where to define the variable will depend on how sublime sets up its shell. Try the following:

1. Just close the sublime window and then open it again and see if it has now re-read your `.bashrc`.
2. Sublime could very well not read `.bashrc` at all. If you are running sublime from some GUI button, you will probably need to log out and log back in before it manages to re-read the variables.
3. Try opening a new terminal and running `sublime` (or whatever the command name for launching sublime from the command line is). Does it see the variable then?

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know. Howere, as you mentioned I am using sublime text app. So far, I was opening my python script which is located on desktop of linux, and then opening terminal on desktop. After changing .bashrc on terminal, I was relaunching Sublime Text to run the aforementioned script.

Comment: @ElisaFo sorry but that still isn't clear. Are you running the script from within sublime or not? Are you launching sublime from a terminal or using some sort of graphical interface? I really don't think sublime would ever read `.bashrc`, it probably sets up the environment as a copy of what you had when you opened sublime. And you didn't have the variable defined there.

Comment: I installed Sublime Text which is a GUI and running the script from within sublime Text GUI, as I was doing in windows, so I am not running the python script from terminal. Yes maybe it's not sync and does not read my modified .bashrc. I'll check

Comment: And you launch sublime from the GUI then? You double click some icon to launch it? Does it work as expected if you open a terminal and run `sublime-text`, then continue from there and run your script in this sublime instance?

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what do you mean by "launch sublime from the GUI". Simply,  I am just opening Sublime-Text which is a software, importing the script inside that and then **Ctrl+B** which runs the script.

Comment: OK, and when you say "open" you mean "double click an icon"? Sorry, but on Linux, many of us don't use the mouse to open programs (I never do) and instead launch from a terminal. Did you try opening a (new) terminal and running `sublime-text`?

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm still using the mouse. Yes I meant double click. I have a windows mentality. I will try